# Can two spinning drives in RAID 0 configuration support 4K ProRes Raw data rates?

Tags: final-cut-pro, prores, storage, raw

I'm helping a friend to assess external storage options. We are *hoping* that a Lacie 2big will be fast enough to support a 4K final cut work flow. Can two spinning 7200RPM drives configured as RAID 0 even play back 4k ProRes raw?

I found an [apple white paper](https://images.apple.com/final-cut-pro/docs/Apple_ProRes_White_Paper.pdf) which looks extremely informative -- **can someone confirm that "Mbps" in this document refers to megaBITS per second?** If so, we see these data rates for ProRes 4444 (no alpha):

```
24p     1697 mbps   212.125 MB/s
25p     1769 mbps   221.125 MB/s
30p     2121 mbps   265.125 MB/s
50p     3539 mbps   442.375 MB/s
60p     4242 mbps   530.25 MB/s
```

If I understand that white  paper correctly, those data rates look pretty high for just two drives. **Does anyone have any personal experience working with 4K ProRes RAW off a pair of spinning drives in RAID 0?** Is this feasible? Or should we be looking at 4-drive or 5-drive units?

Comment: If you have the hardware already, and you're on a Mac, the [BlackMagic SpeedTest app][1] is a great way to see what video your system is capable of reading and writing.


  [1]: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/blackmagic-disk-speed-test/id425264550

Comment: @tomh we do not yet have the hardware, and are wanting to avoid buying anything that doesn't do the job. thanks for the comment, though! that looks handy.